# uncountable noun used with countable noun

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

> The controller controls **power** supplied to **the PCs**.

Does the sentence above imply that each PC will be supplied with an equal amount of power? If so, does the following make sense when each PC may be supplied with a different amount of power?:

> The controller **individually** controls power supplied to the PCs.
>
> The controller controls power supplied to **each of** the PCs.

Comment: The short answer to your original question is "No."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that doesn't imply that it will be equal. If you want to make it very clear that the control is individual, you can do that with a small change, but there's no implication that the control *isn't* individual in the original sentence.

The small change to make it clearer that the control is per-PC could be:

> The controller controls **the** power supplied to **each** PC.

---

By the way, "the controller controls" sounds a little naff, just because of the repetition. You might want to look at alternative words there. But that's an issue with composition, not the actual correctness of the language.

Comment: Is it possible to insert "individually" between "controller" and "controls" in your sentence in order to make the individual control much clearer ?

Comment: Yes, that's a place you can put an adverb. You could use *separately* or *individually*, as long you do use *each* or similar as well. It's unnecessary, but it does emphasise the separateness.